# Dynamic parameter selection in Jenkins scriptler

Tags: groovy, build, jenkins, parameterized, jenkins-scriptler

I have a parameterized build job in Jenkins which takes few parameters.

My requirement is to dynamically modify the values in the parameter dropdowns based on previous parameter selection.

Like the parameters will be

1. Release Name
2. Technology Component
3. Build Number

So what i need is , if the person triggering the build, first selects the parameters from top to bottom, if he selects a Release 1.0 then the Technology component drop down should populate like Web App, Web service, Jar file and based on the technology component selection, the Build Number drop down should pull the build #s from corresponding technology component's job.

How can i achieve this using the plugins in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you can use the [Jenkins Dynamic Parameter Plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in), which seems to fit your requirements.

Comment: the jenkins dynamic param plugin does not have the ability to change depending on a value selected from another parameter in the same build ....

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use a validation plugin and manipulate the next dropdown. 
It may help you.,
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Form+Validation